# Table in PHP shows duplicate columns from array

Tags: php, html-table, multiple-columns

I wrote code for writing table from array variable, but it shows duplicate columns:

[image]

Here is array values:

```
    $data = [
    [
        "title" => "The World's End",
        "genre" => "Sci-fi",
        "year"  => 2013,
        "gross" => 21
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Scott Pilgrim vs. the World",
        "genre" => "Sadness",
        "year"  => 2010,
        "gross" => 21
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Hot Fuzz",
        "genre" => "Buddy Cop",
        "year"  => 2007,
        "gross" => 21
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Shaun of the Dead",
        "genre" => "Zombie",
        "year"  => 2007,
        "gross" => 21
    ],
];
```

And table writing code:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($data as $item){
            foreach ($item as $key => $drop){
                echo '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($data as $item) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $item['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item['genre']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item['year']; ?></td>
        <td>€ <?= $item['gross']; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>€
            <?php
            $gross_sum = 0;
            foreach ($data as $gross_value)
            {
                $gross_sum += $gross_value['gross'];
            }
            echo $gross_sum;
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I remove repeating right column side in the table from my code content?

Comment: Why are you generating the table headers from the data this way? I would either do it manually or have a multidimensional array with a key for headers and one for data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        foreach ($item as $key => $drop) {
            echo '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

with this:

```
<tr>
    <?php
    foreach (array_keys($data[0]) as $item) {
        echo '<th>' . $item . '</th>';
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

There function `array_keys` return keys to show in header.

Comment: I went to put a solution together before scrolling down. This is **exactly** what I did. To make it a little easier to read i did assign the function call to `$headers` but that's just a personal pref

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a nested foreach loop at the beginning, so you'll be iterating over each entry in `$data` and then iterating over key again. For your headers, you only need to iterate over the keys once. Have a look at the code below, I've made a small change to your first foreach loop.

```
<?php

$data = [
    [
        "title" => "The World's End",
        "genre" => "Sci-fi",
        "year"  => 2013,
        "gross" => 21
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Scott Pilgrim vs. the World",
        "genre" => "Sadness",
        "year"  => 2010,
        "gross" => 21
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Hot Fuzz",
        "genre" => "Buddy Cop",
        "year"  => 2007,
        "gross" => 21
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Shaun of the Dead",
        "genre" => "Zombie",
        "year"  => 2007,
        "gross" => 21
    ],
];
?>

<html>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($data[0] as $key => $item){
            // foreach ($item as $key => $drop){
                echo '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
            // }
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($data as $item) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $item['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item['genre']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $item['year']; ?></td>
        <td>€ <?= $item['gross']; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>€
            <?php
            $gross_sum = 0;
            foreach ($data as $gross_value)
            {
                $gross_sum += $gross_value['gross'];
            }
            echo $gross_sum;
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `current` to get the first element of the array and `array_keys` to get the keys. Combining this inside a foreach should solve your problem.

```
foreach (array_keys(current($data)) as $key) {
    echo "<th>$key</th>";
}
```

In addition to that, it's often the better way to define the header statically (except, you don't know the content of the table),

```
$header = ['title', 'genre', 'year', 'gross'];
foreach ($header as $text) {
   echo "<th>$text</th>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I took this as a chance to write it as I would. Hopefully it provides some use to you.

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        "title" => "The World's End",
        "genre" => "Sci-fi",
        "year"  => 2013,
        "gross" => 21,
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Scott Pilgrim vs. the World",
        "genre" => "Sadness",
        "year"  => 2010,
        "gross" => 21,
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Hot Fuzz",
        "genre" => "Buddy Cop",
        "year"  => 2007,
        "gross" => 21,
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Shaun of the Dead",
        "genre" => "Zombie",
        "year"  => 2007,
        "gross" => 21,
    ],
];

// Let's grab your headers
$headers = array_keys($data[0]);

// Format them by capitalizing the first letter
$headers = array_map('ucfirst', $headers);

/**
 * You could also inline it into one assignment
 * This decreases readability, but removes the quick reassignment of $header
 *
 * $headers = array_map('ucfirst', array_keys($data[0]));
 */

/**
 * Let's calculate the gross here instead of in the presentation (HTML)
 */
$total_gross = array_reduce($data, function ($gross, $movie) {
    $gross += $movie['gross'];

    return $gross;
}, 0);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($headers as $header) :
            printf('<th>%s</th>', $header);
        endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($data as $movie) : ?>
        <tr>
            <?php
            printf('<td>%s</td>', $movie['title']);
            printf('<td>%s</td>', $movie['genre']);
            printf('<td>%s</td>', $movie['year']);
            printf('<td>€ %s</td>', $movie['gross']);
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <?php printf('<td>€ %s</td>', $total_gross); ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```